# yii2 form input ajax validation will not perfom

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

im trying to active ajax validation in my form according the docs i added(
'enableAjaxValidation' => true and validationUrl )with its action
can anyone tell me why validation will not perform on my form ?
i dont have any error in console

thankyou

this is my controller

```
public function actionCreate()
{

    $model = new Developers();

        return $this->render('_form', [
            'model' => $model
        ]);

}


public function actionValidation(){

    $model = new Developers();
    if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) )
    {
        Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }
}
```

and its my form

```
<div class="developer-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => $model->formName(),
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
        'validationUrl'=>\yii\helpers\Url::toRoute('site-admin/validation')
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['minlength'=>true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'family')->textInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'phone')->textInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'address')->textInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'brithday')->textInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'age')->textInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'ability')->textInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'role')->textInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'point')->textInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'join_date')->textInput() ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

and here my model rules function

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['name',
            'family',
            'phone',
            'email',
            'address',
            'brithday',
            'age',
            'ability',
            'role',
            'point',
            'join_date',
            ], 'required'],
        [['id'], 'integer'],
        [['date_project_done','estimate_for_next_project','number_of_project','activity_rate','free_rate','project_done'], 'safe'],
        [['address'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        [['name'], 'string', 'min' => 3],

    ];
}
```

Comment: Can you check in browser console if validation action is called?

Comment: @Fabrizio Caldarelli
validation action not calling.  why ?

Comment: Have you checked if there are javascript syntax error in your code?

Comment: console error log is clear

Comment: Try to comment 'validationUrl' to check if ajax request is made. Also, 'validationUrl' should be an array or string, so it should be only ['site-admin/validation'], http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html#$validationUrl-detail

Comment: Do you validate that $model->formName() is not null? Also try debugging your code in controller see if you actually enter the if statement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code in view file form variable :

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                'id' => 'login-form', //your form id
                'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
                'enableClientValidation' => false,
                'validateOnBlur' => false,
                'validateOnType' => false,
                'validateOnChange' => false,
            ]) ?>
```

Use below code in your controllers action :

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Developers();
    if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) )
    {
      if($model->validate())
      {
        // do here anything 
        $model->save();
      }
      else
      {
        Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
      }
    }
    else
    {
     return $this->render('_form', [
        'model' => $model
     ]);
    }
}
```