# Yii2 Ajax Modal Post With Ajax Validation Works But Model Does Not save

Tags: yii2-model, yii2-validation

**There are many suggestions to begin the controller code with this:**

```
 if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request- 
 >post())) 
 {
     Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
     return ActiveForm::validate($model);
 }
```

**I have tried a few standard methods following validation such as this without success:**

```
if($model->save()){

 return $this->redirect(['index']);
         }
       }

       return $this->renderAjax('create', [
         'model' => $model,
     ]);
```

My question is what code can be placed under the call to 'return ActiveForm::validate($model)' to successfully execute $model->save upon successful validation ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a working solution and here is the link:

[yii2 form input ajax validation will not perfom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772753/yii2-form-input-ajax-validation-will-not-perfom)

Please note that I had originally an ajax post script appended to the form which is not required for this to work, and so I removed it. It seems that enableAjaxvalidation sends the post as an AJAX request anyway on submitting the form.

Also, this must be in both the controller and the form page:

use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

Answer (score 0):

```
if($model->save(false)){

 return $this->redirect(['index']);
         }
       }

       return $this->renderAjax('create', [
         'model' => $model,
     ]);
```